# Сортировка Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'        => $this->id,
        'comment'   => $this->message,
        'date'      => $this->created_at->format('d.m.Y H:i:s'),
    ];
}
```

Подскажите как отсортировать по `created_at` чтоб новые были вверху ?

Comment: Так не проще отсортировать выборку? До того как вы её отдаёте в ресурс

Comment: Сделайте себе скопу которая будет сортировать по времени и загрузите её с моделью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда делаете выборку, сразу сортируйте. Например `Comments`

```
$comments = Comments::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
```